# UITextView save attributed text

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have `UITextView` with some custom text. User can edit that text (change it, change some fonts, colour of text, highlight parts of text etc...) threw attributes of `UITextView` attributedText property.

When user is done with changing all that I need to save that newly created "Note" (whole changed text with attributes). How can I do that? Note that if there is 20 words in `UITextView`, 1, 5, 10,11,15th word can be red, 2,4,5 underlined and so on (so special ranges for each attribute) and I need to save all that on new place. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, so you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to serialize and deserialize the attributed string to where you wish to save (user defaults, Core Data, etc.).